# Is there a way to write and DateAdd and DatePart SSIS Expression to always generate ThisWeekMonday's date using Getdate()?

Tags: ssis, expression, dateadd, datepart

I have a package that needs to be run every Monday, because the file dates all have Monday's dates for each week that it is sent.  If the package fails for some reason, I want to I to write it in such a way that anybody else can rerun it on any other day of the week.  Regardless of which day it is run, it must generate Monday's date of each week to pick up the correct file.

I tried using the following expression, but it generated last week's Monday's date when it is run on a Monday:

```
DATEADD( "dd", -1 - (DATEPART("dw", GETDATE()) + 4) % 7, GETDATE()  ).
```

I altered the parameters several times, but still couldn't get it to work.

Someone gave me this expression, but it didn't work at all for Monday even after changing the parameters:

```
DATEADD( "dd", (DATEPART( "dw", GETDATE() )  -3), GETDATE()  )
```

Finally, I tried using the following statement which is equivalent to a Case statement in SQL, but it gave me an error in the first part of each line shown below (NOTE: square brackets were not included.)

```
[  DATEPART( "dw", GETDATE())  ]
```

See my complete expression below:

```
DATEPART( "dw", GETDATE())  == 1 ?  DATEADD( "dd", 1, GETDATE()) : (
DATEPART( "dw", GETDATE())  == 2 ?  DATEADD( "dd", 0, GETDATE()) : (
DATEPART( "dw", GETDATE())  == 3 ?  DATEADD( "dd", -1, GETDATE()) :  (
DATEPART( "dw", GETDATE())  == 4 ?  DATEADD( "dd", -2, GETDATE()) :  (
DATEPART( "dw", GETDATE())  == 5 ?  DATEADD( "dd", -3, GETDATE()) :  (
DATEPART( "dw", GETDATE())  == 6 ?  DATEADD( "dd", -4, GETDATE()) :  (
DATEPART( "dw", GETDATE())  == 7 ?  DATEADD( "dd", -5, GETDATE()) ))))))
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following expression:

```
DateAdd("dd", 2 - DatePart("dw", GetDate()) , GetDate())
```

To explain, 2 (which is Monday) - any other day of the week gives you the day offset which can be added to the current day.

e.g. 2 (Monday) - 6 (Friday) = -4 so adding -4 days to Friday gives you Monday.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Apologies for the late response, as I was away on vacation.  I tested your formula, and it worked perfect.  Thanks also for explaining it, as I just couldn't get how DateAdd worked.  So in breaking it down,if I am correct, the offset determined by (2 - DatePart("dw", GetDate()) is added back to the current date obtained by the last  GetDate() expression, which brings it back to the Monday of any week.  Very cleverly done. And thanks a million for your help.